# How to return 403 Forbidden from an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I am writing an Azure function in c# that performs some custom authorization.  If authorization fails, I'd like to return a 403.  I've tried the following:

1. `return new ForbidResult();`
   this gives error message:

   > 'No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultForbidScheme found'
2. `return new StatusCodeResult(403);` 
   this just gives me blank page in both Firefox and Edge.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `return new StatusCodeResult(403)` works.

The blank page is because you're not returning any content. Use developer mode (F12) to verify. If you want to append a message you could do:

```
    return new ObjectResult("Error 403 Forbidden")
    {
        StatusCode = (int?)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

Is it a HTTP triggered function?

```
return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

Answer (score 1):

For functions with HttpTrigger when custom auth fails (due to missing credentials or insufficient rights or alike), I return like this:

- for status code only error responses [CreateResponse] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse(v=vs.118).aspx) `request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)`
- for error responses with hint what went wrong [CreateErrorResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createerrorresponse(v=vs.118).aspx) `request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "You have insufficient rights for this mighty resource")`

For reference [rfc2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 401 is better suited for case where *big nono happened in scope of auth*. According to w3 403 means

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

Where 401 states

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials. If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information. HTTP access authentication is explained in "HTTP Authentication: Basic and Digest Access Authentication".

This thing from [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48230451/1842492) should work as well ;)